# How to auto-configure git merge tool based on what is available on current machine?

Tags: git, bash

I am working a many system and at least on some of them my home directory is stored on NIS, so I do share that same preferences.

I do want to write a small bash script which I can include inside `~/.bash_profile` which will configure the best diff tool which is already installed on current machine.

The rule is simple, I have to check which command line diff tools are available and configure git to use the first one that I found.

Side note: On one linux machine I discovered that there is and ENV variable `__git_mergetools_common=$'diffuse ecmerge emerge kdiff3 meld opendiff\n\t\t\ttkdiff vimdiff gvimdiff xxdiff araxis p4merge\n'` - I have no idea what is this used for, but it looks interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest answer is to write a bash script that runs as the diff program, and selects the best available actual diff program each time.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, still it fails because the diff program which is preferred by different tools is different, so after detecting it, you have to configure it.

Comment: @sorin Ok, I thought you talking just about `git`, since that's your tag on the question. I guess a script per tool is probably atill the easiest option.